# the set of all real numbers whose decimal representation contain only 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 is not countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Explain why the set of all real numbers whose decimal representation contain only  0, 2, 4, 6, 8 is not countable

Comment: For the same reason the set of all real numbers whose decimal representation contains only $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ is not countable.

Comment: As a way to get intuition, note that in base $5$ every real number would be written with $5$ digits ($0,1,2,3,4$ in this case).  And those strings are in bijection with yours.

Comment: Please improve your title and add some context to the body of your Question.  The issue of infinite cardinality is not ordinarily considered a topic in discrete mathematics, if that is what you have in mind by using the phrase "discrete logic".  (The phrase means something entirely unrelated to an electronic engineer.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider that the base 5 representation of *any real number* is a string of the characters $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ (and the decimal point).

Comment: Which lulu said while typing this....

Answer (score 0):

Exact same reason as all reals with any decimal representation is not countable.

Or why $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N} = \{\text {sequences containing only 0 and 1}\}$ is not countable.

Or why the set of any sequence of terms drawn from any finite set with at least two elements is uncountable.

Let $K$ be any finite set.  In your case $K = \{0,2,4,6,8\}$

Let $S$ be the set of all sequences of elements of set $K$ or let $S$ be any set in a 1-1 corespondance.

In your case the set of all such decimals is $\{n.a_1a_2a_3....\}$ and the fractional parts $.a_1a_2a_3...$ coorespond to the sequence of elements $a_1,a_2,a_3...$

Let $f$ be a mapping $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow S$.

Lets create an element,$M$,  of $S$ in this way:   $f(1) =a_1, a_2, a_3,.....$ (or in your case $n.a_1a_2a_3.....$.  The first term of $M$ will be anything in K that isn't $a_1$.  To find the $i$-th term of $M$ we find $f(i) = k_1,k_2,....$.  The $i$-th term of $M$ will be anything in $K$ that is not $k_i$.

The created element, $M$ will not equal any $f(m)$ because the $m-th$ term of $M$ will be different than then $m$-th term of $f(m)$.  So $f$ can not be surjective (complete) mapping to $S$.  So $S$ can not be 1-1 with $\mathbb N$.  So it is uncountable.